# Present Perfect: Active or Passive?

Tags: tense

Which is right: 'I cannot open the door. It has stuck' or 'I cannot open the door.
It has been stuck'?

Comment: I would use "It is stuck" unless there is implication of an action (ex. "It got stuck again").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot open the door. It has stuck.

I cannot open the door. It has been stuck.

When you use the verb stick as an intransitive verb to mean to become so fixed in a position that it's difficult to move, you cannot use the verb in the passive.

Although, the sentence "it has stuck" is grammatical, it's more idiomatic if you use the verb in the simple past or use the adjective "stuck" in the present as follows:

It stuck.

It is stuck (it's stuck).

You can also use got before the stuck in informal English:

It got stuck.

It has got stuck is also OK, but it's less common.

Answer (score 4):

We would say **It is stuck** (or **It's stuck**) or **It has got stuck** (or **It's got stuck**).

(*Note:* AmE would use *gotten* in place of *got*.)